# How to export pixel art from google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I tried to make a pixel art in google sheets by coloring cells.How can I export this as jpg or png.Is there any add ons or scripts for that?

Comment: Hey I have a script for converting it to PDF. Would that be something you are interested in?

Comment: I don't think this is going to be possible without some kind of library that knows how to manipulate those files.